# Excel VBA: How to find the *second last* row with *content*?

Tags: vba, excel, row, rows

Suppose there are `100` rows in column `A`. `90` of them do contain content, line `100` is the sum of all cells in column `A` (lower than `100`), excluding the `9` empty ones.

Now, suppose that the *second* last row *with content* is row `95`. How can I find it when writing VBA code?

I know how to find the *last* row with content. The code for it is:

```
LastCellA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Just subtracting `1` won’t do the job, as you see. So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find the second last non-empty cell

```
LastCellA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

SecondLastCellA = LastCellA - 1
Do While .Cells(SecondLastCellA, "A") = ""
    SecondLastCellA = SecondLastCellA - 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Function findSecondLastRow(sht As Excel.Worksheet, colLetter As String) As Long

    Dim LastCell As Long, SecondLastCell As Long

    With sht.Columns(colLetter)
        LastCell = .Range(colLetter & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range(colLetter & LastCell - 1) = vbNullString Then
            SecondLastCell = .Range(colLetter & LastCell).End(xlUp).Row
        Else
            SecondLastCell = LastCell - 1
        End If
    End With

    findSecondLastRow = SecondLastCell

End Function
```

Call the function by passing as parameters the sheet reference and the letter of the search column, e.g.:

```
Debug.Print findSecondLastRow(ActiveSheet, "A")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

assuming you're interested in the last cell with a *constant numeric* value (i.e. not text and or not formulas)

```
Function MyLastCellRow(ws As Worksheet, colIndex As Long) As Long
    With ws.Columns(colIndex).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        With .Areas(.Areas.Count)
            MyLastCellRow = .cells(.Rows.Count).Row
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

if you are interested in the last cell with a *constant* value (i.e. text and/or number but not from formulas) then just take that `, xlNumbers` off from `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)`

Answer (score -1):

```
mybottom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcellA = .cells(mybottom -1,"A").end(xlup).row
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are no gaps.  In my test worksheet I filled rows 1-10 with the numbers 1-10.  You can find row 10 easy enough but the next one finds row 1 because there are no breaks.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
lr = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Same issue as the other answer, returns top row of data unless there is a break in the data.